# Dynamic Criteria - Filtering Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to filter on the same criteria, but the values of the criteria are not always the same in the data that I receive, so they need to be dynamic.

for eg.

Dim crit1 as String
crit1 = ?

So that:

Selection.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=crit1

here is my code

```
enter code herexDim TaskType, Status, Elapse As Long
Dim Total, Completed As Variant
Total = Array("COMPLETED", "ERROR", "KILLED")
Completed = Array("COMPLETED")
TaskType = WorksheetFunction.Match("tasktypeid", Rows("1:1"), 0)
Status = WorksheetFunction.Match("status", Rows("1:1"), 0)
Elapse = WorksheetFunction.Match("elapse", Rows("1:1"), 0)
'Use Filter Criteria
'100 Total
With Sheets("Raw_Data")
Set rnData = .UsedRange
With rnData
.AutoFilter field:=TaskType, Criteria1:="100"
.AutoFilter field:=Status, Criteria1:=Total, Operator:=xlFilterValues
.Select
        For Each rngarea In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
        lcount = lcount + rngarea.Rows.Count
        Next
        a = lcount - 1
   End With
      End With
'100 Completed
    With Sheets("Data")
    Set rnData = .UsedRange
    With rnData
    .AutoFilter field:=TaskType, Criteria1:="100"
    .AutoFilter field:=Status, Criteria1:=Completed, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .Select
            For Each rngarea In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
            lcount1 = lcount1 + rngarea.Rows.Count
            Next
            b = lcount1 - 1
       End With
          End With

'101 Total
    With Sheets("Raw_Data")
    Set rnData = .UsedRange
    With rnData
    .AutoFilter field:=TaskType, Criteria1:="101"
    .AutoFilter field:=Status, Criteria1:=Total, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .Select
            For Each rngarea In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
            lcount2 = lcount2 + rngarea.Rows.Count
            Next
            c = lcount2 - 1
       End With
          End With
'101 Completed
    With Sheets("Data")
    Set rnData = .UsedRange
    With rnData
    .AutoFilter field:=TaskType, Criteria1:="101"
    .AutoFilter field:=Status, Criteria1:=Completed, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .Select
            For Each rngarea In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
            lcount3 = lcount3 + rngarea.Rows.Count
            Next
            d = lcount3 - 1
       End With
          End With
```

In above code i have calculated criteria1:= as 100,101 statically but it should take dynamic value present in the filter. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use your macro recorder and filter the data, use the custom filter and "Contains". Then look at the filter code produced. From there you will see how it uses wildcards.

Comment: hey i tried but it gives static values.

Comment: Yep, you are doing it to see what the code looks like when using wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

For example,
Using my macro recorder to filter Column "I" for items that contain "a", I would get this kind of code.

```
Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'

'
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$I$1:$I$7").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*a*", _
                                              Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

Now I see how the code uses wildcards and I can now edit the code to use wildcards and my variable.
My New code would look like this.

```
Sub FilterForA()
    Dim s As String
    s = "a"
    Columns("I:I").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & s & "*"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Daveexcel, but the value which you are passing ie., s = "a" is not dynamic i dont want to make changes in code, whereas it should automatically take the values present at the time of filter. As you can see in my code the value Criteria1:="100" is present what if later it could be 600 so that changes i want.

Comment: Again, I am just showing you how to use variables in the filter code. How you set those variables is entirely up to you.